# Hoy can i use placeholder on HTML date time picker?

Tags: date, datetimepicker

How can i create custom date time picker? Where i can use custom placeholder like normal text input box. using js? The date time picker will show "select you date of birth" and user can click on it and then the box will show the calender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can’t make custom styles for data picker. Option is to make 3 inputs as numbers in same row or 3 dropdown box with values of date in same row.

Comment: so the only option is using caption outside of the datetime input sir?

Comment: @BikashChowdhury yes. You can still style inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do with span absolute style css

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).